# How to create a pull to refresh tableview / scrollview in titanium?

Tags: android, titanium, refresh, scrollview, tableview

Since last 2 days i have been searching how to implement this Pull to Refresh thing like they had shown in Tweetanium.

I found some informative code snippets like

**1. http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/05/how-to-create-a-tweetie-like-pull-to-refresh-table.html**

But this one works only for the IOS only.

Another one is

**2. https://gist.github.com/903895**

This works fine with android but it has limitation that every row must be given a predefined height.

If I am getting the content to put in Row form some random JSON response then in that case I can not predefine the height of ROW in table. Thus I cannot calculate the height for the table and breaking the code.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but for the next people, if you use Alloy (and you should!) http://alloylove.com/#pulltorefresh is an excellent solution.